# Кидает I/O Error 6 при первом нажатии на кнопку

Tags: delphi

Вот проверка файла на верность введённых данных и процедура, которая берёт с файла данные и суёт в таблицу. При первом нажатии на кнопку, которая выполняет этот код, стабильно вылазит I/O Error 6. При нажатиях после первого всё хорошо и нормально работает. И так при каждом запуске формы. Почему это происходит и как исправить?
Ссылка на пастебин с кодом: https://pastebin.com/WnmKQn3X

```
function CheckFile(var UserFile: TextFile; Size: Integer; Path: String): boolean;
var
    I, Value: Integer;
    IsCorrect: Boolean;
begin
    AssignFile(UserFile, Path);
    Reset(UserFile);
    IsCorrect := True;
    I := 0;
    while not(SeekEoLn(UserFile)) and IsCorrect do
    Begin
        Try
            Read(UserFile, Value);
        except
            IsCorrect := False;
        End;
        Inc(I);
    End;

    if I<>Size then
        IsCorrect := False;

    CloseFile(UserFile);
    CheckFile := IsCorrect;
end;

procedure TForm1.N4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    I, Size: Integer;
    UserFile: TextFile;
    Value: Integer;
    Path: String;
begin
    Size := SpinEditMas.Value;
    Path := OpenDialog1.FileName;
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    Begin
        if CheckFile(UserFile, Size, Path) then
        begin
            AssignFile(UserFile, OpenDialog1.FileName);
            Reset(UserFile);
            for I := 0 to SpinEditMas.Value-1 do
                Begin
                    Read(UserFile, Value);
                    StringGrid1.Cells[i, 0] := IntToStr(Value);
                End;
            CloseFile(UserFile)
        end
        else
            MessageDlg('Данные в файле некорректны', mtError, [mbOK], 0)
    End;
    if Length(StringGrid1.Cells[0,0]) > 0 then
        Button2.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Comment: Поместите код в тексте вопроса без ссылок

Comment: @andreymal, а сам скопипастить не мог?

Comment: @Qwertiy нет конечно, это нарушение авторских прав — код на pastebin не имеет лицензии, разрешающей его копирование и перелицензирование

Comment: А в каком месте-то ошибку кидает? В режиме debug запусти и покажи строку на которой останавливается.

Comment: Похожий вопрос тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655503/is-there-a-way-to-solve-an-i-o-error-6-in-delphi (может стоит писать System.Reset() вместо reset() и т.п.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При первом запуске переменная `Path` инициализирована непонятно чем. Точнее пустой строкой.

А при каждом следующем - файлом, выбранным в прошлый раз.

Исправить

```
Path := OpenDialog1.FileName;
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
Begin
```

на

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
Begin
    Path := OpenDialog1.FileName;
```